# Chrome textboxes do not have a style on autofill

Tags: css, google-chrome

So whenever I pre-fill a textbox and view it with Chrome, it doesn't show the style I assigned to my textboxes. Why? I will show you a picture what I mean:

[image]

Here is the css code I have:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill {
 -webkit-box-shadow:   0 0 0 50px #000 inset;
 -webkit-text-fill-color:  cyan;
 -webkit-border-radius:   3px;
 -webkit-transition:   all 0.10s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:    all 0.10s ease-in-out;
 transition:     all 0.10s ease-in-out;
 border:     1px solid #006161;
 padding-left:    5px;
 padding-right:    5px;
 float:     left;
 outline:    none;
 opacity:    1.00;
 border-radius:     3px;
 background-color:    #000;
 color:     cyan;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow:   0 0 0 50px #000 inset;
 -webkit-text-fill-color:  cyan;
 -webkit-border-radius:    3px;
 border:     1px solid cyan;
 outline:     none;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:hover {
 -webkit-box-shadow:   0 0 0 50px #000 inset;
 -webkit-text-fill-color:   cyan;
 -webkit-border-radius:    3px ;
 border:     1px solid cyan;
 outline:     none;
}



.txt, INPUT[type="submit"]
{
 background-color:    #000;
 color:       cyan;
    border:      1px solid #006161;
    border-radius:     3px;
    transition:     all 0.10s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:   all 0.10s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.10s ease-in-out;
 padding-left:    5px;
 padding-right:    5px;
 float:       left;
}

.txt:focus, [type="submit"]:focus
{
 opacity:     1.00;
 background-color:    #020202;
 color:       cyan;
 outline:      none;
 border-color:     cyan;
 box-shadow:     0 0 10px cyan;
}

.txt:hover, INPUT[type="submit"]:hover
{
 opacity:     1.00;
 background-color:    #000;
 color:       cyan;
 outline:      none;
 border-color:     cyan;
 box-shadow:     0 0 10px cyan;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='txt' name='settings[".$settings['email']['id']."]' value='".$emailAddress."' />
```

Thanks in advance,

Sapphire ~

Comment: What is it I'm supposed to see when I run your snippet?

Comment: @Madbreaks The darker colored textboxes, but the pre-filled one doesn't show the style.

Comment: You'll want to include some HTML then.

Comment: I have included the css file in my html, it just doesn't style the pre-filled textboxes.

Comment: You've created a snippet for us in your question, but it *displays nothing because you haven't included your HTML in the snippet*. And so it's useless.

Comment: Oh nvm... I guess I was not paying attention... I removed the class variable in the html but forgot to put it back later on.